# Decoding ISO-8859-1 and Encoding to UTF-8 before MySQL query

Tags: php, python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm kinda stuck if I'm doing it right.

I have a file which is ISO-8859-1 (pretty certain). My MySQL db is in utf-8 encoding. Which is why I want to convert the file to UTF-8 encoded characters before I can send it as a query. For instance, First I rewrite every line of the **file.txt** into **file_new.txt** using.

```
line = line.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

And then I save it. Next, I create a MySQL connection and create a cursor with the following query so that all the data is received as utf-8.

```
query = 'SET NAMES "utf8"'
cursor.execute(query)
```

Following this, I reopen **file_new.txt** and enter each line into MySQL. Is this the right approach to get the table in MySQL utf-8 encoding? Or Am I missing any crucial part?

Now to receive this data. I use `'SET NAMES "utf8""` as well. But the received data is giving me question marks � when I set the header content type to

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

On the other hand, when I set

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

It works fine, but other utf-8 encoded data from the database is getting scrambled. So I'm guessing the data from **file.txt** is still NOT getting encoded to utf-8. Can any one explain why?

PS: Before I read everyline, I replace a character and save the **file.txt** to **file.txt.tmp**. I then read this file to get **file_new.txt**. I don't know if it causes any problem to the original file encoding.

```
f1 = codecs.open(tsvpath, 'rb',encoding='iso-8859-1')
f2 = codecs.open(tsvpath + '.tmp', 'wb',encoding='utf8')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('\"', '\''))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

In the below example, I've utf-8 encoded persian data which is right but the other non-enlgish text is coming out to be in "question marks". This is precisely my problem.

**Example :** Removed.

Comment: If your original file is encoded in `ISO-8859-1` then this is the right encoding for it, converting it to `utf-8` probably will generate unknown characters like the question mark you get.

Comment: But that's the whole point of utf-8 right? I shouldn't be getting those questions marks right? Please have a look at my example I provide. It has a utf-8 encoded arabic text and some non-english chracters replaced by question marks.

Comment: Please...do mention what Python version you are working with

Comment: I'm working with Python 2.7.

Comment: Not sure that iso-8859-1 is an encoding that should be used with persian characters.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 handles western Europe and does not handle Persian.

Comment: Can you get a hex dump of a little of the source file?  And provide what you think the file is saying.  That may help deduce what needs to be done.

Comment: @RickJames I've solved the problem mate. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, so my encoding was right. The file was getting encoding to utf-8 just as needed. All the queries were right. It turns out that the other dataset that was in Arabic was in ISO-8859-1. Therefore, only 1 of them was working. No matter what I did.

The Hexeditors did help. But in the end I just used sublime text to recheck if my encoded data was utf-8. It turns out the python script and the sublime editor did the same. So the code is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
line = line.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8-sig')
```

From the docs:

> As UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding no BOM is required and any U+FEFF
>   character in the decoded string (even if it’s the first character) is
>   treated as a ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE.
>
> Without external information it’s impossible to reliably determine
>   which encoding was used for encoding a string. Each charmap encoding
>   can decode any random byte sequence. However that’s not possible with
>   UTF-8, as UTF-8 byte sequences have a structure that doesn’t allow
>   arbitrary byte sequences. To increase the reliability with which a
>   UTF-8 encoding can be detected, Microsoft invented a variant of UTF-8
>   (that Python 2.5 calls "utf-8-sig") for its Notepad program: Before
>   any of the Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded
>   BOM (which looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is
>   written. As it’s rather improbable that any charmap encoded file
>   starts with these byte values (which would e.g. map to
>
> LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE
>   QUOTATION MARK INVERTED QUESTION MARK in iso-8859-1), this increases
>   the probability that a utf-8-sig encoding can be correctly guessed
>   from the byte sequence. So here the BOM is not used to be able to
>   determine the byte order used for generating the byte sequence, but as
>   a signature that helps in guessing the encoding. On encoding the
>   utf-8-sig codec will write 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf as the first three bytes
>   to the file. On decoding utf-8-sig will skip those three bytes if they
>   appear as the first three bytes in the file. In UTF-8, the use of the
>   BOM is discouraged and should generally be avoided.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html

**EDIT:**

Sample:
`"Hello World".encode('utf-8')` yields `b'Hello World'` while `"Hello World".encode('utf-8-sig')` yields `b'\xef\xbb\xbfHello World'` highlighting the docs:

> On encoding the
>   utf-8-sig codec will write 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf as the first three bytes
>   to the file. On decoding utf-8-sig will skip those three bytes if they
>   appear as the first three bytes in the file.

**Edit:**
I have made a similar function before that converts a file to utf-8 encoding. Here is a snippet:

```
def convert_encoding(src, dst, unicode='utf-8-sig'):
    return open(dst, 'w').write(open(src, 'rb').read().decode(unicode, 'ignore'))
```

Based on your example, try this:

```
convert_encoding('file.txt.tmp', 'file_new.txt')
```

Comment: Just tried. Didn't make a difference. I suppose that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Have you tried checking the file encoding? Try opening the file in a text editor like sublime and you should see its encoding from `ANSI` to `UTF-8-BOM`.

Comment: First off, it's a 500 MB file. Also, I've been advised not to test the file encoding with file editors because they ususally guess and make it an even more confusing task. I think the best way would be to check by scripting.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a sample snippet. As @WombatPM pointed out, check your encoding. If your data is too big, start off with a tid bit of sample text from the original file. :)

Comment: I'll try this some time soon. But given my data set I'm not very optimistic about this  :( because i've tried various such combinations and the encoding type wasnt the problem. I'll try this though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of unicode and windows.  I've found this site very helpful in understanding what is going wrong with my strings http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html.  The other thing you need is a hex editor like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/).  There are many places where things can go wrong.  For example, if you are viewing your files in a text editor - it may be trying to be helpful and is silently changing your encoding.

Start with your original data, view it in HxD and see what the encoding is.  View your results in Hxd and see if the changes you expect are being made. Repeat through the steps in your process.

Without your full code and sample data, its hard to say where the problem is.  My guess is your replacing the double quote with single quote on binary files is the culprit.

Also check out [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)
by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The editor you suggested is for windows only. I'm a linux user. And yes, even I felt like the replace quite was the problem. Which why is why I modified it as above and still it gives me the problem.

Comment: Choose a different one then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors.  My mistake on windows.  But the key is to see what really is going on with the data.  Since utf-8 and iso-8859 are multi-bytes formats, I would do your string replace as regular instead of binary.  Also, now would be a great time to try out Python3

Comment: Alright, You're idea of editing text file by hex seems to be a good alternative. But I still have to convert the iso-8859-1 chars to utf-8. How do i do that on hex editors?

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* need to do any explicit encode or decode.  `SET NAMES ...` should match what the *client* encoding is (for `INSERTing`) or should become (for `SELECTing`).

MySQL will convert between the client encoding and the columns's `CHARACTER SET`.

Comment: So, you're saying that setting a PHP header to utf-8 will automatically make the queries on the page to be received as utf-8? This seems rather strange because I've read up in various places like this to ensure safety at each level of the transaction.  https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysqlhttps://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

Comment: If you have a "form", it needs something like `<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep - is that link an ad?  That's naughty.

Comment: Yes, I did those changes to the form but I've observed several times that missing of the safe checks causes some arbitrary problem. And nope, it wasn't an ad. I didn't want any users from this website to come to my messy demo pages :P